# How to write a Play JSON writes converter for a case class with a single nullable member

Tags: scala, playframework, scala-2.10, playframework-2.3

In Play 2.3, I have a case class with a single optional double member:

```
case class SomeClass(foo: Option[Double])
```

I need a JSON write converter that handles the member as nullable:

```
implicit val someClassWrite: Writes[SomeClass] = ???
```

The [Play docs provide an example](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/ScalaJsonCombinators):

```
case class DisplayName(name:String)
implicit val displayNameWrite: Writes[DisplayName] = Writes {
  (displayName: DisplayName) => JsString(displayName.name)
}
```

But sadly I can't figure out how to do this for 1) a single nullable and 2) a double. Any ideas? Thanks.

**Update #1:** The only solution I can come up with is this:

```
implicit val someClassWrite: Writes[SomeClass] = Writes {
  (someClass: SomeClass) => someClass.foo match {
    case Some(f) => JsNumber(BigDecimal(f))
    case _ => JsNull
}
```

**Update #2:** Ignore my solution. Travis Brown's is the one.

Comment: All the play docs example does is transform a `String` to a `JsString`, to which there is no analog for `Option[Double]` in JSON. Could you provide some more context?

Comment: @LimbSoup See those same docs: `case class DisplayName(name:String)
val nameReads: Reads[DisplayName] = (JsPath \ "name").read[String].map(DisplayName(_))`. That works perfectly for a reads converter, by using `.readNullable[Double]` instead. I'm looking for the equivalent writes converter.

Comment: `writeNullable[Double]` ??

Comment: @LimbSoup I wish... `value map is not a member of play.api.libs.json.OWrites[Option[Double]]`

Comment: What are you trying to map? Like I said, more context is needed..

Comment: @LimbSoup I don't know, because I'm not familiar with how Plays OReads/OWrites works. I'm simply following the docs, which works in the reads case, but not the writes case. I appreciate your help with this; it is an esoteric Play libs question, and thus the context lies within those Play libs, and so for me to provide you more context would require me being more deeply familiar with how the play Json libs work, which is entirely my problem.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

`Writes` isn't a covariant functor, so you can't use `map`, but you can use `contramap`:

```
import play.api.libs.json._
import play.api.libs.functional.syntax._

implicit val someClassWrites: Writes[SomeClass] =
  (__ \ 'foo).writeNullable[Double].contramap(_.foo)
```

If you have more than one member, you can use Play's `FunctionalBuilder` syntax:

```
case class AnotherClass(foo: Option[Double], bar: Option[String])

implicit val anotherClassWrites: Writes[AnotherClass] = (
  (__ \ 'foo).writeNullable[Double] and
  (__ \ 'bar).writeNullable[String]
)(ac => (ac.foo, ac.bar))
```

In the first case the argument to `contramap` is just a function from the type you want a `Writes` for to the type in the `Writes` you're calling `contramap` on. In the second case, the function at the end is from the target (`AnotherClass` here) to a tuple of the `Writes` instances you've built up with `and` (in this case `Option[Double]` and `Option[String]`).

Comment: is this documented anywhere? I cant find it and have been fighting this for more than should be necessary lol . the contramap bit that is

Answer (score 2):

The easy way is:

```
import play.api.libs.json.Json

implicit val fmt = Json.format[SomeClass]
```

Which uses a macro to auto-generate the json format for you. Beats implementing writes directly.

Comment: I should add that it's part of a complex system of Writes... recursive writes etc. Is there a hard way?

Comment: If your case class' property is `someId:String` and the JSON element containing your `someId` is "some-ID" then you can't use the macro-generated format.