# Play JSON Reads/Writes with single-parameter case classes

Tags: json, scala, playframework

This creates a `Writes` for a case class

```
import play.api.libs.json._
import play.api.libs.functional.syntax._

case class A(a: String, b: String, c: String)
(JsPath.write[String] and
    JsPath.write[String] and
    JsPath.write[String])(unlift(A.unapply))
```

This can be extended  to work for 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, etc. parameters...but not 1.

```
case class B(a: String)
(JsPath.write[String])(unlift(B.unapply))
```

Compiler error:

```
error: overloaded method value write with alternatives:
  (t: String)(implicit w:  play.api.libs.json.Writes[String])play.api.libs.json.OWrites[play.api.libs.json.JsValue] <and>
  (implicit w: play.api.libs.json.Writes[String])play.api.libs.json.OWrites[String]
  cannot be applied to (B => String)
              (JsPath.write[String])(unlift(B.unapply))
                           ^
```

A similar problem happens for `Reads`.

How can I get `Reads` and `Writes` for single-parameter case clases?

Comment: See my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26458085/334519)—you want plain old `contramap`, since the applicative builder syntax doesn't work with a single element.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Like Travis said:

1. Transforming an existing Reads: use the map method
2. Transforming an existing Writes: use contramap

However, contramap only works on Writes that produce JsObject. Your writes will fail at runtime:

```
val w = JsPath.write[String].contramap[B](_.a)
scala> w.writes(B("Hello"))
java.lang.RuntimeException: when empty JsPath, expecting JsObject
```

You can create a Writes "from scratch" using [`Writes.apply`](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/api/scala/index.html#play.api.libs.json.Writes$):

```
Writes[B](b => JsString(b.a))
```

Similarly you can create a Reads using Reads.apply.

Comment: Thanks. I knew I could always use `Reads.apply` and `Writes.apply`...it just looked odd in my code. "Here's a case class, and another one, and...oh...that looks different." Thanks for help.

Answer (score -2):

implicit val reads: Reads[A] =
    (JsPath \ "ax").read[B].map(A.apply)