# Compiler error Reads[T] for single path

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0

The Play 2.5.x docs do not provide an example I can use to try and sort my problem with defining an implicit Reads[T] for my model.

Could someone point out what I am doing wrong please?

My model:

```
case class Entry(id: Int, typ: String, caught: ZonedDateTime)
case class Data(entries: Seq[Entry])
```

The following Reads for the Entry type is fine.

```
 implicit val entryReads: Reads[Entry] = (
      (__ \ "id").read[Int] and
      (__ \ "typ").read[String] and
      (__ \ "caught").read[ZonedDateTime]
    )(Entry.apply _)
```

---

**The problem**

is with my `Reads[Data]` below. The compiler is complaining that it needs a Data instead of an Entry.

Found: `Reads[api.test.Entry]` required: `Reads[api.test.Data]`

```
implicit val dataReads: Reads[Data] = (JsPath \ "entries").read[Seq[Entry]]
```

---

If I modify Data so that it has multiple fields.

```
case class Data(entries: Seq[Entry], someStr: String)
```

Then my dataReads using the combinator compiles fine.

```
 implicit val dataReads: Reads[Data] = (
      (__ \ "entries").read[Seq[Entry]] and
      (__ \ "someStr").read[String]
    )(Data.apply _)
```

The problem is my Data  does not really need that String.

The Play docs contain plenty of examples of defining implicit Reads/Writes for Case classes with more than a single field but none that have a single field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at map.

```
implicit val dataReads: Reads[Data] = (
        (__ \ "entries").read[Seq[Entry]].map(Data(_))
    )
```

You might be interested in this post if you need to define a `Writes[T]` as well - [How to write a Play JSON writes converter for a case class with a single nullable member](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26457395/how-to-write-a-play-json-writes-converter-for-a-case-class-with-a-single-nullabl)

Answer (score 0):

If you use multiply fields, you use functional syntax and `FunctionalBuilder.apply` function, which fills `Data.apply` parameters:

```
implicit val dataReads: Reads[Data] = (... and ...)(Data.apply _)
```

is same

```
val dataBuilder: FunctionalBuilder[Reads]#CanBuild2[Seq[Entry], String] = (... and ...)

implicit val dataReads: Reads[Data] = dataBuilder(Data.apply _)
```

For one field Reads functional syntax is not used, so you must fill `Data.apply` parameters by yourself with mapping `(__ \ "entries")` to `Data.entries`

```
implicit val dataReads: Reads[Data] = (
  (__ \ "entries").read[Seq[Entry]].map(Data)
)
```